# Spring-Security with OAuth2Login & CustomAuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

In my case I have an OAuth2 login with a CustomAuthenticationProvider.
Now I have the problem that the CustomAuthenticationProvider is not called and I don't know why.

The login works so far without problems.

My properties that I have set for the client registration:

```
# CLIENT FOR AUTHORIZATION CODE GRANT #
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.login-client.client-id=client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.login-client.client-secret=secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.login-client.client-authentication-method=client_secret_basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.login-client.scope=openid, profile, roles
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.login-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.login-client.redirect-uri=redirect-uri
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.login-client.issuer-uri=issuer-uri
```

My SecurityConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Value("${keycloak.logout.uri}")
    private String logoutUri;

    @Autowired
    private KeycloakAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        // Required for zkoss-uploads
        http.headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable();

        // Required for zkoss-logins
        http.csrf().disable();

        // Authorization on request
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        // OAuth2 Client
        http.oauth2Client();

        // OAuth2 Login
        http.oauth2Login();

        // Logout handling
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl(logoutUri);
    }
}
```

And my CustomAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class KeycloakAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException
    {
        System.out.println("authenticate");
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)
    {
        System.out.println("support");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: My CustomAuthenticationProvider has no logic yet because I wanted to see if it is called first.

EDIT:

My dependencies:

```
<!-- Security -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
  <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
  <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't know which version of Spring Security you are, but you can try using `http.authenticationProvider(...)`

Comment: my spring-security-client version is: 5.6.1
About the http.authenticationProvider(...) I have also tried... 
unfortunately without success

Comment: I have added the dependencies to the post.

Comment: I think you should try debugging the invocations of `AuthenticationManager#authenticate`. Maybe your provider is not invoked because other provider is returning a valid authentication before

Comment: why are you mixing versions of spring security?

Comment: Okay that was my mistake. I have fixed the dependencies now. But unfortunately the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved my problem myself.
The problem was that the configuration of `http.oauth2Login()` provides its own `AuthenticationProvider` and this is not overwritten with the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

My solution was to add a `successHandler` to the `oauth2Login`.
This has the task to rework and set the existing authentication that is created by the auto-config.

Here is my code:

```
@Autowired
private KeycloakAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;

http.oauth2Login().successHandler(successHandler);
```

and my successHandler:

```
@Component
public class KeycloakAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    @Value("${logging.groupId}")
    private String location;

    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        var persistedAuth = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
        var user = new DefaultOAuth2User(persistedAuth.getAuthorities(), persistedAuth.getPrincipal().getAttributes(), "name");

        /*
         * Sets new OAuth2AuthenticationToken with mapped authorities
         */
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .setAuthentication(new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(user, mapAuthorities(persistedAuth.getPrincipal().getAttributes()), persistedAuth
                        .getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId()));

        /*
         * Redirecting to the index page of website
         */
        var redirectUri = requestCache.getRequest(request, response).getRedirectUrl();
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUri);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> mapAuthorities(Map<String, Object> attributes)
    {
        var resourceRoles = new ArrayList<>();
        var resourceAccess = (Map<String, List<String>>) attributes.get("resource_access");
        if (resourceAccess.containsKey(location))
        {
            resourceRoles.addAll(((Map<String, List<String>>) resourceAccess.get(location)).get("roles"));
        }
        return resourceRoles.isEmpty() ? emptySet() : resourceRoles.stream().map(r -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(valueOf(r))).collect(toSet());
    }
}
```

Btw: Thanks to Marcus, through the tip with the debugger I found the solution!